# how to hide other href links when we click any one href links , links are dynamic

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function addChildAccord(childAccord) {
    var abcde = childAccord.toString();
    var element = document.createElement("input");
    //Assign different attributes to the element.
    element.setAttribute("type", "text");
    element.setAttribute("name", "abcde");
    element.setAttribute("id", "abcde");
    element.setAttribute("value", abcde);
    element.setAttribute("readonly", "readonly");
    var createdElem = document.getElementById("filterElementId");
    //Append the element in page (in span).
    createdElem.appendChild(element);
}

function check(link) {
    alert(link);
    $(link).replaceWith($(link).text());
}
```

//this creates dynamic links and I need when user clicks any link, other link should hide or disable
    
        
        
            
                
                    ${autnValue}

Answer (score 1):

You can hide links by adding some class

```
$('body').on('click','input',function(){
   //Hide all links
   $('input').addClass('hidden');
   //Unhide clicked one
   $(this).removeClass('hidden');
   ...
   //other code
   ...
});
```